# How to disable red underlines in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am coding with the latest version of Visual Studio Code with Python. For some reason I get those red underlines on my code, where there would be a "problem". The annoying part of this is that I get it even while still typing the code. Could someone please tell how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may also be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(or <kbd>command</kbd>) + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then type disable error squiggles then disable it like that. This works for c/c++ so I am not sure if it will work on python! This also disables it showing all errors